# VueJS2: v-if with multiple expressions does not work

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to hide a div element using the v-if directive in an HTML element like so:

```
<template v-if="(selectedProducts != 'Static Graphic' || selectedProducts != 'Other Support')">
  <div><strong>Content 2 Here</strong></div>
</template>
```

But, this doesn't work.

What's the correct way to write this logic/expression? [**MY JSFIDDLE demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/jqqpdqgx/)

Thank you,

Comment: So it seems that according to the VueJS docs, multiple expressions are not allowed in directives in VueJS2. Did I read that right? I should move this logic into the computed property?

Answer (score 1):

You can put an expression in v-if.
The problem is with your expression: selectedProducts is an Array, you can't test `selectedProducts != 'Static Graphic'`

Try this:

```
v-if="(selectedProducts.indexOf('Static Graphic') < 0  && selectedProducts.indexOf('Other Support') < 0)">
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/thierry36t/x2kc55p0/1/

Answer (score 0):

VueJS has awesome documentation so You should take a look here first https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Here You can skip *template* tag and move v-if into the div like this:

```
<div v-if="selectedProducts != 'Static Graphic' || selectedProducts != 'Other Support'">
 Now you see me
</div>
```

Take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/bqe05f2w/1/

Update for Your particular case:

```
<template v-if="selectedProducts.indexOf('Static Graphic') > 0 || selectedProducts.indexOf('Other Support') > 0">
  <div><strong>Content 2 Here</strong></div>
</template>
```